Conditional Access Authentication Context availability on Azure B2C Tenant
Is Conditional Access Authentication Context not supposed to be available on Azure B2C Tenant? I have an Azure B2C Tenant with PremiumP1 pricing tier. When I go to manage that tenant via "Open B2C Tenant" or switching the current directory and navigate to Conditional Access | Authentication contexts, the "New authentication context" is disabled. The pricing tier seems to be inherited from the linked EntraId for the subscription which is PremiumP1 and I don't see anyway to change it. I have confirmed that Conditional Access Authentication Context is available on the linked EntraId but we need it on B2C tenant where the users (customers) are authenticated.
Screenshots of the Entra ID and B2C tenant:







In my Microsoft Entra ID Tenant, the "New authentication context" is enabled:

But when I checked in B2C tenant, the option is disabled:

To check whether the license is present in B2C tenant, check Licenses in B2C tenant:


Note that: Azure AD B2C is a separate service from Microsoft Entra ID and doesn't inherit licenses from it. Refer this MsDoc

Hence you need to register with Microsoft Entra ID P2 in the B2C tenant:

After configuring the license, you will be able to add new authentication context.


I have access to two subs under two completely independent tenants. One of the tenant is "Microsoft Entra ID P1" and another one is "Microsoft Entra ID P2". In both the subscriptions I have created B2C tenant and made sure those are "PremiumP2". In any of the B2C after switching the tenant, I see Licenses as disabled even though I am Global Admin in both B2C tenant as well as Global Admin in one of the subscriptions' tenant.

In one of the subscription where I am Global admin on the tenant, I went through the process of activating the "Microsoft Entra ID P2" and I can see the license under admin.microsoft.com. I have assigned one license to myself and to another user. Both of us still can't see the Authentication Context under the B2C's Entra Tenant. It seems the license somehow needs to be assigned at B2C level. How?

Thanks @Rukmini for the details along with the screenshots. I have few more questions after I can get it to light up about the license requirements e.g. how this license apply to B2C users where the pricing is based on MAU? I am looking forward to using auth context for the B2C users and obviously $9 per user per month isn't something that would work for the volume of B2C users.

Can you paste the screenshot of the licenses page in Azure B2C tenant

@amit_g is the issue resolved?

posted the screenshots in the question

Please raise a support request as it should work
